# Instance member 'index' can't be accessed using static access

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm trying to access a variable from another StatefulWidget

```
_cardList.add(InputRefNomProduit(
index: j,
.
.
delete: () {
setState(() {
_cardList.removeAt(InputRefNomProduit.index)
})
}
```

the index variable is defined in the InputRefNomProduit class :

```
class InputRefNomProduit extends StatefulWidget {
int index;
.
.
InputRefNomProduit({
.
.
this.index,
.
.
});
```

and this is the error i get :

```
Instance member 'index' can't be accessed using static access.
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell which instance you want the `index` of. `InputRefNomProduit` is a class name. You have a list with multiple instances of that class.

Which one do you want to remove there? You haven't shown us enough code to see what you exactly want.

Comment: the _cardList is a list that contains a bunch of InputRefNomProduit() . and I want each time I add a new InputRefNomProduit to the _cardList , I want to get their index using the index variable.

Comment: the delete parameter is a button that will delete an InputRefNomProduit  based on the index.

Answer (score 0):

```
void main() {
  int i = 555;
  //instance of NoobClass 
  NoobClass noobClass = NoobClass(index: i);
  //call getter
  int indexFromNoobClass = noobClass.getNoob();

  print(indexFromNoobClass);
}

class NoobClass {
  int index;

//constructor
  NoobClass({required this.index});
//getter
  getNoob() {
    return index;
  }
}
```

Comment: the variable is used in the constructor of InputRefNomProduit , so static can't be used .

Comment: i added an example above detailing how to initialize a variable in a class constructor and getter for accessing the value of the variable